# What does p-value mean in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I want to apply a t-test on two independent samples, and decide whether sample_2 is greater than sample_1. Below are the results for two different `t.test`s I ran on the samples :

default parameters : 
    t.test(sample_1,sample_2)

```
        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  sample_1 and sample_2
t = -1.8795, df = 1121.445, p-value = 0.06043
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.45823402  0.09580241
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 45.08116  47.26238
```

alternative "greater" :

```
> t.test(sample_1,sample_2,alternative="greater")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  sample_1 and sample_2
t = -1.8795, df = 1121.445, p-value = 0.9698
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.091665       Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 45.08116  47.26238
```

alternative "less" :

```
t.test(sample_1,sample_2,alternative="less" , paired=FALSE)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  sample_1 and sample_2
t = -1.8795, df = 1121.445, p-value = 0.03022
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
       -Inf -0.2707661
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 45.08116  47.26238
```

can someone please explain me what are the meaning of p-values in these two tests?

the first p-value 0.06, is this the probability that they are equal, or that they are **not** equal?

And the second value 0.97, does that mean sample_2 > sample_1 , or vice versa : sample_2 <= sample_1 ?

This is a very basic question but I cannot understand from other resources. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "*the first p-value 0.06, is this the probability that they are equal, or that they are not equal?*" -- NEITHER. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value

Comment: Thanks, but I really cannot comprehend the sentence `"the probability of obtaining a test statistic result at least as extreme as the one that was actually observed, assuming that the null hypothesis is true"`
I just want to use this statistical tool to statisctically accept or reject my working hypothesis : "data_source_2 > data_source_1". So please forgive my impatience but I really don't have much time to understand these concepts, so I just want to make a decision. So what is the "most acceptable" answer to my question : is the mean of sample 2 larger than sample 1?

Comment: "*I really don't have much time to understand these concepts*" -- this seems bizarre given it's actually the answer to the question *in your title*, so it would seem essential to understand it (why spend all that time posting if you don't care to understand the answer to your question?). What happens the next time you have such a question?

Comment: @Glen_b I was trying to make a final project report for my course so I hope I won't have such a question again :) Thanks for all the help though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any p-value is the answer to this question:

> If, in the population from which this sample was randomly drawn the
>   null hypothesis was true, what is the probability of getting a test
>   statistic at least as extreme as the one we got in the sample we used?

This is *neither* of your answers. It is not the probability that one value is greater, different or the same as another.

In the first case, the null is that the means are equal. So, the p is saying that, if they were equal in the population, you  would get $|t| > 1.87$ about 6% of the time. The second case is just silly (it looks like you should have put "lesser" where you put "greater") but, as written, the null is that the mean of x is at least as big as y; since the sample mean of x is smaller, you get a really high p value.

Comment: Thanks! So the second probability, (using a 5% confidence interval), does it mean sample_2 is greater than sample_1, or not? I will also put the output with "less".

Comment: It's not a 5% CI it's a 95% CI and the second p value says you have a 97% chance of getting a  t at least as extreme as the one you got if the null is true.

Comment: So I have a 97% chance of getting a sample from sample_2 which is bigger than a sample from sample_1 ?

Comment: No. Read what I wrote. IF the null hypothesis is true you have a 97% chance of getting a t statistic at least as far from 0 as the one you got.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The *p*-value tells you the *probability of the  under the null hypothesis*. The null hypothesis can be a wide range of things, but using your example, in the first case, it is: sample 1 and sample 2 represent the same distribution. In the second case, it is: the inferred parameter is greater for the population from which the second sample was drawn, compared to the first.

- The *p*-value does *not* inform you about the probability of the *sample means* or *the data*. The *t*-test is about the inference of population parameters given some data. The sample means you do not need to infer; you already know them! x is smaller than y. The *p*-value talks about the probability of observing such a sample, given the null hypothesis, and the null hypothesis concerns not the **sample**, but the **population** from which you sample. 
  The sample itself does not have a probability of occurring - or rather, its posterior probability is 1, since it *has* occurred. You should look at *p*-values if what you want to know is how likely this occurrence would have been, given the null.
- The *p*-value also does *not* directly inform you about the direction of the difference for the population from which the two were sampled. (However, the sign of the *t*-value can help you make inferences about this, if only *t* is available; here, since your *t* is negative, the sample mean for x is smaller than for y. This only works with *t*, not with, for example, *F* values! Also, *t* is about the sample, not about the population.)
- Finally, the *p*-value does *not* tell you about the **probability of *hypotheses* (P(H|D))**, but about  the probability of **the data you observe, given a hypothesis (P(D|H))**. For the first test, it tells you that a sample this much, or more different from the distribution proposed by the null hypothesis would be rather rare (~6% of cases), *if the two samples come from the same population*. In the second test, it tells you that if the hypothesis that y is greater than x was true, data like this would be very common (~0.97% of cases). 
  Conventionally, a so-called *alpha*-level of 5% is used as a cut-off point to *reject* a hypothesis, since the data would be sufficiently rare if it were to be true. If a *p*-value does not make this cut-off, it is then however not inferred that the null hypothesis, which we cannot reject, is true; many other hypotheses could be as, or more, likely. Instead, we simply say that the hypothesis under test could not be rejected.
  Treating this convention as a binary rule (which is, and can, be done in some contexts) would mean that neither of your tests is informative, since you cannot reject either hypothesis. Commonly, a *p*-value very close to the .05 convention is called "marginal".
- Naturally, your 6% result then leads you to the problem that your data is very unlikely under the null, but not sufficiently unlikely to reject the null at the conventional 5% level. One way of dealing with this would be to focus on the 95% CI; in this case, it tells you that you can say, with some confidence (whatever this means), that the mean of the population from which x has been sampled is smaller or, if at all, only larger by a very small amount, compared to the population for y. (What this "confidence" specifically means is problematic; fundamentally, a CI is also about the probability of the observed data given a range of hypotheses.). Another way would be to focus on the third test; however, such one-tailed tests are controversial in some venues.

In short, what you can take from a *t*-test *p*-value is the following: if it is very low, the observed data would be surprising for anybody putting faith in the specific hypothesis under test, where the hypothesis concerns the population from which you have sampled.
So what you can take from your specific *p*s is:

1. Such data would be rare if the two samples come from the same distribution, but not sufficiently rare to reject the hypothesis that the mean of population 1 is neither smaller nor greater than in 2 at the 5% level.
2. Such data would be very common if sample 2 comes from a population where the inferred parameter is larger than for 1.
3. Such data would be rare if *sample* 2 comes from a population where the inferred parameter is smaller than for 1. The hypothesis that *population* 1 > *population* 2 can be rejected at the 5% level, given the low probability of the data under this hypothesis. (However, running multiple tests on the same data, as you did here, is problematic; as is choosing tests *post hoc*.)

Comment: Please check your first sentence. It seems to be missing some words.