# How to calculate p-values for logistic regression coefficients?

Tags: logistic, p-value, regression-coefficients

First I am not a stat person so I don't know much about core details of p-values.

I have the LR coefficient values for the features. I want to know the p values of those features. I know that I can calculate the odds value by simply calculating $e^{coeff}$. However I want to know how to calculate p values with lr coefficients.

Also another thing I don't know much about it is the evaluation of p-values. Is it higher the better or vice-versa?

Comment: There are many elementary discussions of the meaning / interpretation of p-values on our site. A simple search will turn up a good few. e.g see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104403/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-large-p-value

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218574/the-true-meaning-difference-of-alpha-values-and-p-values?s=7|1.2260

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests?s=13|0.9909

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96316/805 ... posts like these should cover your second question